# Outlook.com webapp

Tags: unity, email, notification, webapps

Does Outlook.com webapp (still called live mail, but that is not important) work even when the browser is not open? I mean let's say I close Chromium to play a game; yet I would like to be notified when I receive a new e-mail. Can webapps in general work this way? Of course when I want to read the mail, the browser will start.

But as far as I can tell, the notifier in the messaging menu works only when browser is running...

Comment: I think that all webapps need the browser to be running in order to have desktop notifications.

Comment: So it is basically a feature, not a bug, right? I tried to run the webapp separately, and it indeeds start as a fullscreen app, but when I checked processes I saw Chromium running anyway, so I guess there is nothing to do about it for now.